# How to open main cover of Samsung ML-1640?

Tags: printer, laser-printer

[image]
[image]
[image]

How to open main cover of this printer: Samsung ML-1640 ?

Comment: See the service manual http://www.ellon.ru/service/samsung_ml-1640_1645_2240.pdf

Comment: @DavidPostill my problem is in (page 45) > (Step 3) They simply said: {Lift the Main Cover after remove the 2 screw} but it seems it's not so easy. :( i'm sure 100% if i do it, the main cover will be broken :'(

Comment: Have you tried to gently **slide** it upwards? And in other directions?

Comment: Did you remove the **other** two screws as instructed? You should have removed **four** screws.

Comment: @DavidPostill i just removed the 2 screws in front of the device and the 2 screws behind the device. should i remove the top layer before removing the main cover? :'(

Comment: I've no idea. I was reading the same manual as you are. You should have **6** screws removed before trying to lift the main cover. (there are **4** screws in step 1 and **2** more in step 3). Also did you already remove the front cover first?

Comment: @DavidPostill i have updated the question with 3 photos. if you check the photo, you'll see i have removed all the screws :'( but i still unable to lift the main cover even with screwdriver! :'( anyway tnx for your help :(

Comment: Did you look at the bottom? Maybe the side panels may need to be moved out slightly to remove the whole cover?

Comment: @DavidPostill yes :'( i have removed anything :( but it seems it's so strong and also brittle :( it seems i have to pay money for it tomorrow :( actually i decided to check its thermistor. it got (Thermistor open) error :( anyway tnx for your time :)

Comment: @Mehdi J did you check that video in the answer

Comment: @NirmalSeneviratne i was unable for open its link.because its not a URL ! please edit its url address if it's possible. tnx

Comment: @Mehdi J Sorry I edited it

Comment: @NirmalSeneviratne Your video was a light in the darkness thank youuuuuuuu <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1st Method

This video should help you .

[Youtube link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pZGzOgKl06A)

### 2nd Method

Follow the steps to open the main cover.

[image: 1]

[Link to the original](http://%20ellon.ru/service/samsung_ml-1640_1645_2240.pdf)

Comment: my problem is in (Step 3) They simply said: {Lift the Main Cover after remove the 2 screw} but it seems it's not so easy. :( i'm sure 100% if i do it, the main cover will be broken :'(

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing). You have clearly copied this photograph from the link in my comment to the question with providing any attribution.

Comment: @NirmalSeneviratne Your video was exactly what i needed, finally i have opened the main cover of the printer... <3 <3 :)

Comment: @Mehdi J    I'm glad that I helped you :)